# Using Mandrill SMTP integration

Tags: c#, smtp, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill to send emails from my application (C#).

I'm using a template from Mailchimp and I have a merge tag `|* NEWUSERCONTENT *|`, to represent the email content.

The problem is that I send the content but I receive only the merge tag. My code:

```
email.Headers.Add("X-MC-Template", "template-1-novo-usuario");
email.Headers.Add("X-MC-MergeLanguage", "Mailchimp");
email.Headers.Add("X-MC-MergeVars", "{\"name\": \"newusercontent\", \"content\": \"teste\"}");
```

Instead of receiving `"teste"` on email content, I receive `|* NEWUSERCONTENT *|`.

I didn't find a clear example on Mandrill KB. Anyone knows how to resolve this?

**EDIT:**

It works, my merge tag was wrong.

But now I found another problem. The real text I want to pass has line break (\n), and in this case, the merge tag doesn't work. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try `*|NEWUSERCONTENT|*` (no spaces, different delimiter order)

Comment: [Here is an example](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582487-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-) that seconds Alex' suggestion to use `*|MERGETAG|*`. (I've [googled for "mandrill X-MC-MergeVars"](http://bit.ly/1Bod3S4))

Comment: It works, my merge tag was wrong. Thanks for help! But now I found another problem. The real text I want to pass has line break, and in this case, the merge tag doesn't work.

Comment: That sounds like a new question.